# Responsive gallery with content

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm a beginner and it's my first time on Stack Overflow so I hope you'll be forgiving :) I'm trying to build small responsive 'gallery' with two pictures and div with text (vide: img). The problem is with these white stripes and inscriptions on pictures. I can't make them behave like pictures - in smaller sizes, they're falling on the bottom. How can I make them "stick" to the pictures? I'm using flexbox.

Thanks for all your answers and patience :)

[image: responsive gallery]

Code:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive{
  max-width: 100%;

}

.box img {
  display: block;

}

.white_stripe {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 329px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  @include tablet {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  @include mobile {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.box p {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .box {
    width: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .box {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
  }
}

.box {
  margin: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .box {
    width: calc(50% - 3rem);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .box {
    width: calc(33.3333% - 3rem);
  }
}

.txt {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

```html
        <div class="container">
          <div class="gallery">
            <div class="box">
              <div class="white_stripe ws_one"></div>
                <img src="images/box1_img.jpg" alt="Chair CLAIR" title="Chair CLAIR" class="responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="box">
              <div class="white_stripe ws_two"></div>
                <img src="images/box2_img.jpg" alt="Chair MARGARITA" title="Chair MARGARITA" class="responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="box txt">
                <h4>Finds all inputs</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
                    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s only a guess, because i haven´t work with flex yet. But what happend, if you make the .white-stripe to `display: block`?

But the more needed answer could be: make .box to `position: relative`.

Comment: Glad, i could help ;)
Which point exactly was it now? Display Block or Position Relative?

And could you perhaps mark this answer as correct please? ;)